# How to solve the problem based on vector triple product

Tags: calculus, cross-product

I m stuck by this problem. I know the formula but I  can't solve this problem.

[image]

Plz help me

Comment: Can you compute $a \times (b \times c)$? It'll be a vector depending on $\theta$. Once you've done that, it's just a component-wise derivative by $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you Henry Swanson, I can compute a×(b×c),yo I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer. By the derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we mean the function $x \mapsto (f_{1}'(x), \dots, f_{n}'(x))$, where $f'_{i}$ denotes the derivative of the $i$th component $f_{i}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Note that the function $\theta \mapsto a \times (b \times c)$ takes $\mathbb{R}$ (for example) to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, so once you get the cross products then you get the derivative of the function.